# How to motivate users give feedback?

Tags: feedback

We have launched a mobile application recently and we are discovering a lot of bugs. We have a "Send feedback" button at the bottom of almost all main screens, which people do not use.

How to motivate them to use this in-system feedback feature?

Comment: When you say they 'don't use' it, do you mean they don't even bother clicking the button, or they click it but don't actually submit any feedback? What tracking do you have in place here?

Comment: They don't click it. They open the site, look for the support e-mail and send e-mails.

Comment: If your users are looking up the support email and sending messages to that, consider having the "submit feedback" button next to it. So, the page would say something like "To contact us, use **this contact form**, or email us at support@example.com" where the part in bold is a clickable link that launches the feedback form.

Comment: If your discovering that you app has alot of bugs people probably aren't using your app hence why your feedback isn't getting traction.

Comment: If the user is sending messages through the support email, it doesn't seem like a lack of motivation problem. It seems that they just aren't seeing the "Send Feedback" button. This may be due to its placement, hierarchy, etc. A screen grab would be helpful in this case.

Answer (score 1):

People don't bother to send feedback because usually there's no reward for doing so. Typing feedback on a mobile phone is time consuming as well. Those two things are major barriers to the user. I don't have research to back it up; it's common sense.

When was the last time that you filled out a form or survey to give feedback for an app or site? It's probably been a while if at all.

You'll have to give tangible rewards like discounts or gift cards via a random draw. If it's the type of app of that users will regularly re-use, they'll be more emotionally invested in the app's stability, but you will still need to reward them.

To be honest, it sounds like the problem is that you're expecting users to help you bug hunt. To me that's like having a store and expecting customers to point out spills or misplaced items for you. That's your responsibility not theirs.

Answer (score 1):

To motivate users to leave feedback in beta-version app you could try use a trick. When application is starting on an Android device show pop-up with information like "We became better. Recently 5 bugs were killed. Report us your bug!" with link to feedback.

At the same time you should be honest with your users.

This pop-up will not break the flow as it shown before the work starts. It could be slightly annoying so auto-close it.

**The idea is to show the meaning and value of feedback and do it explicitly!**

Answer (score 1):

To make the user give up 5 min. of his time, you need to give something in return. That something can be a prize (works every time) or access to advanced/restricted application features or just VIP access to customized zones.

If you can't find any "incentive" that works for your users you can always try to support that feedback request with a story that has a meaning for the user (sometimes a simple story and a little bit of sincerity does the trick).

And there's always "the hard way" :) You can try to integrate feedback as contextual feedback on actions and flows (simple questions with straight answers spread around the application), this way you can increase your chances to get something relevant and even simplify the process for the user.

Answer (score 0):

When your application crashes for any reason, have a dialog box saying "the app crashed. would you like to let the developer know so he can fix it?". A lot of app devs do it and it seems to work

Comment: Note Android does this by default for certain types of crashes (all?)

Answer (score 0):

You can just mention or notify the users while using the app that : "Your feedback is important to us. In case of any problems/errors please feel free to give your valuable feedback"

Using such language on popups will be great and users will let to know that **feedback** feature is available and can be used.

Hope this might help you.